# ufw prevent all connection from my java app

Tags: java, ubuntu, rmi, ufw

Right now am working on distributed app
using java rmi, CLIENT-SERVER after create simple connection:
between SERVER(Linux in my case ),the CLIENT(cant reach server)

> **PROBLEM** : CLIENT can't reach SERVER

the only thing that prevent the conn is FireWall (ufw),
after adding rules to allow the connection in specific port
its still the same problem, i tried also to scan the SERVER.
for any open port using nmap, the default port of rmi =1099 is open,
but still the SERVER *unreachable* from CLIENT side, in the other hand 
when *disable* ufw every thing *work just fine*.

> **ufw** status verbose

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: reject (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
443                        DENY IN     Anywhere                  
1099/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
1099/udp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
443 (v6)                   DENY IN     Anywhere (v6)             
1099/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
1099/udp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

> **NMAP** OUTPUT FOR OPEN PORTs

```
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-11-05 09:24 Europe de l?Ouest
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.9
Host is up (0.00030s latency).
Not shown: 999 filtered ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
1099/tcp open  rmiregistry
```

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 21.73 seconds

> **Suggestion ???**

Comment: Unless you show us how ufw is configured we can just guess.

Comment: Also, this looks more like material for [serverfault](https://serverfault.com)

Comment: i dont think, cause when disable the ufw it's work

Comment: Ok, then disable it, problem solved!

Comment: you want me to allow all incomoing connection :D

Comment: I was teasing you, to be frank. My point is: of course you don't want to disable the firewall, but at the same time you can't expect help with your firewall if you don't tell us how the firewall is configured. I see that now you posted the configuration, so the point is moot. Now let's see if we can figure it out.

Comment: Stupid question, maybe, but are you 100% sure that your app is trying to connect to port 1099? Also take a look at [ufw's logs](https://serverfault.com/questions/516838/where-are-the-logs-for-ufw-located-on-ubuntu-server) just to be sure you're actually trying to connect and ufw blocks you.

Comment: latelly i'm using the tools to gather information (nmap, wireshark) to insure 
every thing working, and yes the app try to reach the server with 1099 port

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off the firewall with the following command

```bash
sudo ufw disable
```

Answer (score -1):

document of my solution

1. Start with disable **ufw**
2. reset the iptables
3. allow all ports you need
4. run the firewall normaly

**1. Disable *ufw***

```
sudo ufw disable
```

**2. Reset the *iptables***

```
sudo iptables -F
sudo iptables –X
```

**3. Allow incomming connection to *rmiregistry = 1099***

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 1099 -j ACCEPT
```

the rules was added by the previous command

```
elhoussam@pc:~# iptables -L --line-numbers
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:rmiregistry

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
```

**4. Run the firewall normaly**

```
 sudo service netfilter-persistent start
```